# Can't clone gitlab's repo via ssh, via http - OK

Tags: gitlab

I'm new to gitlab and CI so i had tons of questions but some of them solved via google, SO, git mans, but not the last ...

I can't clone repo via ssh =(

If i try to clone repo via http:

```
lesha@lesha-SeoTeam:/var/www$ git clone http://gitlab.vbox/root/virtualboxgitlab.git
Cloning into 'virtualboxgitlab'...
Username for 'http://gitlab.vbox': root
Password for 'http://root@gitlab.vbox':
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

That's OK!

But via ssh ...

```
lesha@lesha-SeoTeam:/var/www$ git clone git@gitlab.vbox:root/virtualboxgitlab.git
Cloning into virtualbox 'gitlab'
git@gitlab.vbox's password:<br />
```

It prompts me git's password which I didn't create during install (as I had in man)

```
rsa keys
```

I added my key via gitlab's web (to account root, actually I didn't create any other accounts)

And also I added key by "cat my_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys"

I read few posts here about ssh troubles, but most have gitolite installed

I installed gitlab 5.3 without gitolite (as in manual), may be I should ?

Also I tried `ssh -vT git@gitlab.vbox` and it outputs :

```
....
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 48:83:ba:b3:37:72:a0:dc:ca:2c:a3:b8:78:a1:c4:ad
debug1: Host 'gitlab.vbox' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lesha/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/lesha/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lesha/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lesha/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@gitlab.vbox's password:


root@seotm-server:/home/git/.ssh# ls -l
итого 4
-rw------- 1 git git 922 Июл 18 21:05 authorized_keys
```

environmetnt: 
debian 7, nginx + passenger, gitlab 5.3, ruby 2.0.0p247 , without gitolite, puma against unicorn

please help!=) i'm stuck ...

---

some additions (20.07.2013):

I created user git as in manual install

```
sudo adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' git
```

The next day, I tried to kill git and re-add simply by `useradd` command, after that my keys are working but i'm still not happy because:

```
lesha@lesha-SeoTeam:/var/www$ git clone git@gitlab.vbox:root/virtualboxgitlab.git
Cloning into 'virtualboxgitlab'...
fatal: 'root/virtualboxgitlab.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

and http works as well as previous:

```
lesha@lesha-SeoTeam:/var/www$ git clone http://gitlab.vbox/root/virtualboxgitlab.git
Cloning into 'virtualboxgitlab'...
Username for 'http://gitlab.vbox': root
Password for 'http://root@gitlab.vbox': 
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

So, now I don't have auth problems but have another one.

How would you troubleshoot this issue from there?

Comment: I have edited my answer in response to the edits of your question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GitLab 5.x doesn't use gitolite anymore](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-without-gitolite/), but [`gitlab-shell`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell).

I would advise to create a dedicated account, as recommended in the [installation process](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md).

```
ssh git@gitlab.vbox
```

That ssh commands means you are asking for a secure shell on '`gitlab.vbox`' as user '`git`'. If that user doesn't exist... it won't work.

There is no need to try and clone repo is the tests doesn't run properly:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598328/user2598328) reports ssh works better after creating the git user and adding the keys, but:

- first make sure you create your keys on a 'client' account', not in `~git/.ssh/id_rsa`: you are trying to open a session as `git`, from a client account. `git` is the account in which gitlab is installed.
- You should then register your public key in the ssh page of the user account you declare through the gitlab gui. You should *not* "`useradd`" an ssh to root.

If you see this:

```
lesha@lesha-SeoTeam:/var/www$ git clone git@gitlab.vbox:root/virtualboxgitlab.git
Cloning into 'virtualboxgitlab'...
fatal: 'root/virtualboxgitlab.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

That also means you shouldn't specify the path of the repo (`root/`):

```
 git clone git@gitlab.vbox:virtualboxgitlab.git
```

It is gitlab job to know where virtualboxgitlab.git is stored (as specified in its `gitlab.yml` config file)

<del>Basically, **forget root**</del>, and do the full installation of gitlab as it was intended: in a '`git`' account.

The OP made it work, commenting that:

> "`root`" is administrators namespace, gitlab creates this url automatically and without it clone doesn't work, now everything clones and I begin to install gitlab CI,

The OP had to:

> add my user to sudo group, made clean install, received error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in initialize': getaddrinfo: 
  Name or service not known (SocketError)
```

which can't resolve hostname, added `gitlab.vbox` to `/etc/hosts`

Comment: I folowed installation guide step-by-step with no errors, with only:   `Git configured for git user? ... no`, my git user exists and `git:x:1001:1001:GitLab,,,:/home/git:/bin/bash`

Comment: added my user to sudo group,made clean install, received error `/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)` which can't resolve hostname, added gitlab.vbox to `/etc/hosts` adn now i'm almost happy!=) one word about the path to repo, you told i shouldn't specify root/ in path, i do and i should, "root" is administrators namespace, gitlab creates this url automatically and without it clone doesn't work, now everything clones and i begin to install gitlab CI, many thanks