# GitLab SSH-Cloning fails; HTTP works

Tags: ssh, gitlab

overflow! Since I am new here and decided to ask a question myself for the first time I hope that I am asking accordingly to the guidelines. Please point out any mistakes.

[Can't clone gitlab's repo via ssh, via http - OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739978/cant-clone-gitlabs-repo-via-ssh-via-http-ok)

My problem is very similar to that one, but I want to make sure I do not have any simple error in my configuration that might cause it.

My setup is Ubuntu 12.10 and GitLab 6.0.2

I used the following guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-gitlab-as-your-very-own-private-github-clone

HTTP cloning works perfectly, but using SSH SmartGit loads forever ("Checking connection to repository") until a message pops up "Waiting for the following process to finish: git.exe ls-remote git@git.server.com:groupname/projectname.git refs/heads/*"

> /home/git/gitlab$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

says everything is alright:

```
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes Has python2? ... yes python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.0 ? ... OK (1.7.0) Repo base directory exists? ... yes Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes post-receive hooks in repos are links: ...  groupname / projectname ... ok

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes Database is SQLite ... no All migrations up? ... yes GitLab config exists? ... yes GitLab config outdated? ... no Log directory writable? ... yes Tmp directory writable? ... yes Init script exists? ... yes Init script up-to-date? ... yes Projects have satellites? ...  groupname / projectname ... yes Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git" Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.10)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

Every time I try to login via SSH, auth.log adds:

```
sshd[processID]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0  
sshd[processID]: Connection from CLIENTIP port xxxx
```

What does the first line mean? The port in the second line seems to vary between 6000 and 8000. Same problem if I disable my firewall. I forwarded port 22 on my router and I try to access the repository via lan.

Using PuTTY I can connect via SSH, login as user "git" with password & key. After login I get a message from gitlab "Welcome to GitLab, Firstname Lastname!" and immediately afterwards "Connection closed by remote host."

I'm stuck at this point. Should I post my sshd.conf? I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: seeing different ports is normal. the client chooses a random port on its end for sending the data from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason SSH works now, without me changing anything server-side. The only thing I did, was committing new files via HTTP.

Sorry I can't offer any explanation; But I'm glad it works now.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using smartGit the problem is caused by "Authentication" configuration. To solve this problem select "Use Smartgit/Hg as SSH client" as default option.