# How to perform ssh to gitlab

Tags: version-control, gitlab

I am trying to setup the gitlab for my project. I have my ssh key setup in gitlab and I wanted to ssh to my project. I got the ssh link from gitlab

```
git@git.calculator.com:calculator/engineering.git
```

However, when I tried to `ssh git@git.calculator.com:calculator/engineering.git` in my terminal I got

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname git@git.calculator.com:calculator/engineering.git: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I got the ssh link from gitlab and I am not sure why can't I ssh to it. Can anyone help me about this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't ssh to a full ssh url.

You can check `ssh git@git.calculator.com` to see if you have (non-interactive probably) ssh access.

But the ssh url mention by GitLab is for cloning (as I mentioned, for instance, in "[Can't clone gitlab's repo via ssh, via http - OK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17740432/6309)"):

```
git clone git@git.calculator.com:calculator/engineering.git
cd engineering
git log
```